# A model for the number of kids in a family and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $0<r<1.$ We model the number of children in a randomly chosen family with the following distribution
>   $$P(\text{exactly $n$ kids})=\frac{1}{2}r^n\quad\text{if }n\geq1,$$
>   and $P(\text{no kids})=1-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{2}r^n$. We assume that the gender of each children is male or female with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ independently of the genders of the other siblings.
>
> What is the probability that a family has no boys given that there are $k$ kids?

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ Using the definition of conditional probability we have that
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
P(\text{no boys}\,|\,\text{exactly $k$ kids})
&=\frac{P(\text{no boys}\cap\text{exactly $k$ kids})}{P(\text{exaclty $k$ kids})}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}r^k\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^k}{\frac{1}{2}r^k}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^k}.
\end{split}\end{equation}
My only concern is with the probability of the event $\{\text{no boys}\cap\text{exactly $k$ kids}\}$. My reasoning for my answer was that since none of the $k$ kids can be a boy, by the assumed independence, we can multiply the $1/2$'s.

---

Do you agree with my attempt at a solution of this problem? If not, please point me in the right direction with a hint, only a hint.

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the right answer. To make the reasoning more rigorous we can start with considering what is given indeed. The assumption

> gender of each children is male or female with probability $\frac12$ independently of the genders of the other siblings

can be rewritten as assumption on conditional distribution: **given** any fixed number $k$ kids in a family, we have $k$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $\frac12$ to determine the number of boys or girls. So the distribution of a number of boys in a family **given that** there are exactly $k$ kids is binomial: 
$$
\mathbb P(m\text{ boys in a family}\mid \text{exactly } k \text{ kids}) = \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{2^k}, \; m=0,1,\ldots,k.
$$

After rewritten condition in this way, you can factor the probability of intersection as
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
P(\text{no boys}\,|\,\text{exactly $k$ kids})
&=\frac{P(\text{no boys}\cap\text{exactly $k$ kids})}{P(\text{exactly $k$ kids})}\\
&=\frac{P(\text{no boys}\mid \text{exactly $k$ kids})\cdot\mathbb P(\text{exactly $k$ kids})}{P(\text{exactly $k$ kids})}\\ 
&=P(\text{no boys}\mid \text{exactly $k$ kids})\\
&=\frac{1}{2^k}.
\end{split}\end{equation}